# compare histogram comparison method isn't working in opencv 3.1.0

Tags: python, opencv3.1

I have to compare two images using `cv2.compareHist()` function. But I got error on the comparison method i.e. `CV_COMP_CORREL`. I use OpenCV 3.1.0.
Error is `NameError: name 'CV_COMP_CORREL' is not defined`.

I tried with `cv.CV_COMP_CORREL` and `cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL`, but I got the same type error.

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread("29.jpg",0)
image1 = cv2.imread("29.jpg",0)
hist1 = cv2.calcHist([image],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
hist2 = cv2.calcHist([image1],[0],None,[256],[0,256])
compare = cv2.compareHist(hist1,hist2,CV_COMP_CORREL)
```

Comment: You may use `0` instead of `CV_COMP_CORREL`

Comment: The name is probably something like "cv2.COMP_CORREL"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're still struggling with this; I found the answer, searching through the `cv2.__dict__` dictionary:

```
for option in cv2.__dict__:
    if 'CORREL' in option:
        print option
```

I find `cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL`.